# Isomorphism class of factor groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Say $G=Z_4 \oplus U(4), H = \langle (2,3) \rangle, K= \langle (2,1) \rangle$. Determine the isomorphism class of factor groups  $G/H$ and $G/K$.

I am able to see that $H , K$ are isomorphic but I don't understand what is meant by isomorphism class.

I also computed order of all cosets in the factor set and found that there are equal number of elements of each order $2,4$. So they are isomorphic, but is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, what does $U(4)$ mean? I suppose $Z_4$ are integers mod 4?

Comment: U(4) is coprimes less than 4.

Comment: By simple arithmetic, you can see that $G/H$ and $G/K$ have 4 elements. A group with 4 elements can be either isomorphic to $Z_4$ or isomorphic to $Z_2 \oplus Z_2$. Sometimes we say: there are just two groups with 4 elements (up to isomorphism!). Your job here is to decide, for each of those two factor groups, are they isomorphic to $Z_4$ or $Z_2 \oplus Z_2$. Isomorphism class of some group $X$ is a class of all groups isomorphic to $X$. So you could rephrase: your job is to determine are those factor groups in isomorphism class of $Z_4$ or $Z_2 \oplus Z_2$.